# Http determine how old is page

Tags: php, http, date, header, creation

I'm working on a crawler and I need to determine how old is a page from server.

I need to do this because I want to parse only pages from last week.

I tried to find some information about HTTP Header, but I can't find any information about page creation date.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check "Expires" in the response header.

Actually, every page or resource you are requested should contain this information.

Comment: That states when a page should go stale or be expected to change, not when it did change.

Comment: So then I do not think there is a way that server tells you where that page has been created or generated or so. There is just no information like that.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers generally do not carry this information. `Age` only carries the age of a document in a proxy cache, which is not what you want here.

However, while not the true age, you can get the last modified date with `Last-Modified`.

Answer (score 0):

As no server is forced to deliver this information the only reliable way I can think of is scanning every week and see if the page changed or not. This of course requires to save all the pages.

Saving the pages could be implemented by only storing a checksum. This checksum could be stored in a directed acyclic word graph if you want to save memory.

The problem with this is that every page with only a little amount of dynamic data can not be identified (dynamic could be changing advertisements).

A combination of Last-Modified and caching could be helpful.